# Transient Boolean Variable Issue

Tags: java, boolean

I have a transient variable that does not exists in the database, it's an interpretation for another variable (integer variable), basically if that int variable equals 2, my transient is True, else it's False. This is my getter and setter:

```
public Boolean getAceitaPix() {
    if(versaoWS.equals(2)){
        this.aceitaPix = true;
    }else{
        this.aceitaPix = false;
    }
    return aceitaPix;
}

public void setAceitaPix(Boolean aceitaPix) {
    if(this.aceitaPix == true){
        this.versaoWS = 2;
    }else{
        this.versaoWS = null;
    }
    this.aceitaPix = aceitaPix;
}
```

The issue is, when I try to make the changes at my XHTML, the getter is called again and it changes the boolean no matter what I do at the Form, so when the setter is called the transient variable is always TRUE. How do I proceed? Do I make another Boolean that only changes the setter? I think there's a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't _have_ a field named `AceitaPix`.  Just have a getter and a setter that interprets it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't need a field there. Instead, you could just have a getter that calculates it on the fly:

```
public boolean getAceitaPix() {
    return versaoWS.equals(2);
}
```